# Assume $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are sequences in X and let $x \in X$ and that $(a_n) \to x$ and $d(a_n,b_n) \to 0$. Prove that $(b_n) \to x$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

Let (X,d) be a metric space. Assume that (a_n) and (b_n) are sequences in X and let x be an element of X. Assume also that a_n converges to x and d(a_n,b_n) converges to 0. Prove that (b_n) converges to x.

Comment: Trying to use the definition of converging, such as "because $a_i$ converges to y, then for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists N in the Naturals such that when n>N, $d(a_i,y)< \epsilon$ ."

Answer (score 1):

$0 \leq d(b_{i},y) \leq d(b_{i},a_{i}) + d(a_{i},y) \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$

We take limit, and we have:

$0 \leq \lim_{i \to \infty} d(b_{i},y) \leq \lim_{i \to \infty} (d(b_{i},a_{i}) + d(a_{i},y)) = 0 + 0 = 0$

So $\lim_{i \to \infty} d(b_{i},y) = 0$

Comment: Is there a way to answer this using epsilon instead of taking limits?

Comment: Yes, let $\varepsilon > 0$

Then there exists $N_{1} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(a_{i},y) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ $\forall i > N_{1}$

And there exist $N_{2} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(a_{i},b_{i}) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ $\forall i>N_{2}$

Then if $N = max\{N_{1},N_{2}\}$, $d(b_{i},y) \leq d(a_{i},b_{i}) + d(a_{i},y) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon$ $\forall i>N$

Comment: Thank you! But how do you know that $d(a_i,b_i)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$? Don't we only know that $d(d(a_i,b_i),0)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$?

Comment: $(d(a_{n},b_{n}))_{n} \subset \mathbb{R}$ then it converges to $0$, it means that $|d(a_{n},b_{n})|<\varepsilon$ $ \forall n>N$... And as $d(a_{n},b_{n}) \geq 0$, $|d(a_{n},b_{n})| = d(a_{n},b_{n}) < \varepsilon$